# Rails 3 Paths not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, path, routes

I have a form to create a new event for an organisation. The routing is:

```
resource :organisations do
  resource :events
end
```

When I edit an event, on success I route back to the show action in the events controller as such:

```
def update
    @organisation = current_user.organisations.find(params[:organisation_id])
    @event = @organisation.events.find(params[:id])
    if @event.update_attributes(params[:event])
        # Handle a successful update.
        flash[:success] = "Event updated"
        redirect_to organisation_event_path
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

When I create an event, I also want it to redirect to the events show action, implemented as follows:

```
def create
    @organisation = current_user.organisations.find(params[:organisation_id])
    @event = @organisation.events.create(params[:event])
    if @event.save
        flash[:success] = "Event added!"
        redirect_to organisation_event_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

However, this produces the following error: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"events"}`

This is because the URI does not have the event ID / name in it, as far as I can figure out. It is probably my lack of understanding of path generation, but how do I achieve the result I want?

Comment: I think you need to pass organization id in to the             redirect_to organisation_event_path because event is created under organization so organization is recognize by organization id.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your first redirect worked, but organisation_event_path will require two arguments since it is creating path from the ids of two resources - organization and event. So, you should call it like this:

```
organisation_event_path(@organization, @event)
```